# Google launcher building

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I tried to build [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/) project using JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA but it was unsuccessful (there were a lot of errors). The project has an Android.mk file, but I didn't see the C++ code.... How can I build this project? I've tried  to use another IDE, then I tried building from the console but it was not useful. Perhaps, does Launcher3 need NDK to build it?

[image: IDE Screenshot]

Comment: The easiest way is to extract the code manually and patiently yourself one class at a time and make sure it runs each time. I know it's not the answer you're looking for. In order to build this project otherwise, you'll need to build it on top of the AOSP. And you'll need to do it from the command line on a Mac or on Linux, but not Windows. And the AOSP does need the NDK. The only book that can help is probably this one. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do And even then, don't expect to get rid of the errors in the IDE, even if everything builds correctly through the command line.

Comment: now, i use ubuntu 14.04, where can i find information how to build it?

Comment: I don't know. I only know about the book I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to isolate the launcher's code and then identify all of it's dependencies. If the code has any C++ code then it definitely requires the NDK and currently IntelliJ/Android Studio does not have any stable support for NDK based app development (though it is a work in progress) else if it is pure Java (most probably) then you'll have to manually add the classes and build the app from Android Studio! Either way you will have to dig deeper into the source and know for yourself. Unfortunately there seems to be no easier option, for now. I wouldn't mind being proved wrong for the matter.

EDIT :

I glanced through the code and I noticed there are no C++ source files or library (*.so) files. This isn't a gradle project and hence cannot be built as one. You'll need to setup a gradle based Android project and then begin adding the sources (src, tests etc.) and their dependencies (res etc.). You can start of here : [Getting Started with Android development](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) if you're new, else you can move to this : [Gradle and Android](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html)